# How to set max form content in jetty or tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jetty

I was getting error "FORM too large" when I submit a form containing many data. As default size for JETTY server is 2 mb and my form size is exceeded.

I solved the issue locally by using system argument in Eclipse ie by setting max form content to -1, which means no limit to form content. But the problem is in UAT environment. How to do that, if we cannot use Eclipse?

Does any one know how to provide this configuration in JETTY or TOMCAT directly so that max form content is unlimited. I have tried the same configuration in `start.ini` file in JETTY but it is not working in UAT.

Please geeks share your idea,if any.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unlimited form content size is actually a form of vulnerability. (Look into how map hash key collision can be a harsh form of DOS attack)

Are you really sure you need to send 2MB of form data?

> Note: `multipart/form-data` content that are FILES (not form fields) are handled with different max size configurations.
>
> Look into the `<multipart-config>` entries in `WEB-INF/web.xml` or `@MultiPartConfig` annotations for more about those limits.